# Multiple Workbook calculations

Tags: excel, series, fill

I have the following calculation going into a master workbook.

```
=SUM('[Budget Our Boys 2017-2018.xlsm]MONTHLY CASH FLOW'!$D$5, '[Closer     Than Ever.xlsm]MONTHLY CASH FLOW'!$D$5, '[Birds.xlsm]MONTHLY CASH FLOW'!$D$5, '[Poppets.xlsm]MONTHLY CASH FLOW'!$D$5)
```

The calculation is for the month of January. I would like to then drag this formula across all other months for the year. However, when I do so, it does not fill the series. !$D$5 stay !$D$5 across all cells and would like it to go as follows:

Dragging across
!$D$5. !$E$5, !$F$5 
Dragging down
!$D$6. !$D$7, !$D$8

Anyone able to help would save me hours of data input.

many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try by removing '$' ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would I remove both $  reading !D5

Comment: This has worked a treat, thanks so much.

Comment: Great, let me post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first time every answering a question so it'd be a pleasure to help. have you tried removing the columns absolute cell reference? cell A1 means a1, cells $A1 means cell a1 but when moved never adjust the "A", cell A$1 means cell a1 but when moved never adjust the "1", and lastly exclamation "!" is a suffix to a sheet name allowing you to target cells from other sheets.

if you wish to be able to drag formulas along say d1=a1+b1 and also have e1=a1+c1 you can simply put in d1

d1=$a1+b1
, drag that formula across to "e" column and as far down as you need and that should work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the understanding. It now makes perfect sense and works wonders

Answer (score 0):

Removing the '$' from the cell references will dynamically update them, relative to each cell. Your new formula should be:

```
=SUM('[Budget Our Boys 2017-2018.xlsm]MONTHLY CASH FLOW'!D5, '[Closer     Than Ever.xlsm]MONTHLY CASH FLOW'!D5, '[Birds.xlsm]MONTHLY CASH FLOW'!D5, '[Poppets.xlsm]MONTHLY CASH FLOW'!D5)
```